# NodeJS modify files with super user permissions

Tags: node.js, file, file-permissions, node-webkit

I want to modify hosts file ( /etc/hosts ) with NodeJS or NW.js. Is this possible?

Comment: Only if your script runs as super user

Answer (score 0):

Run your NodeJS script as super user and see if that helps.